# hitbox iframe on https site

Tags: html, iframe, ssl, https

I've added cloudflare ssl to my site, but I have following issue:
The iframes of hitbox stream

```
<iframe class="stream" width="65%" height="40%" src="http://hitbox.tv/#!/embed/'.$channel.'" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

are not appearing on the site, and they are not working over https. How can I add them?

Answer (score 1):

Back in 2014 hitbox didn't support HTTPS-embedding. But now they do. 
So you could just try it again.
Be aware that your code won't work anymore though, you'll have to change the URL from
`http://hitbox.tv/#!/embed/'.$channel.'` to `https://hitbox.tv/embed/'.$channel.'`

You can also embed the chat using the URL `https://hitbox.tv/embedchat/'.$channel.'` or, if you want the chat to auto-connect, you can also append `?autoconnect` to the URL.

Comment: FYI: Unfortunately, embedding *videos* via HTTPS is still broken.

Comment: @xrstf Not really, it's working perfectly fine for me. Where and how is it broken for you?

Comment: I'm trying to embed this video: https://www.hitbox.tv/video/258014 -- requesting this URL directly redirects to http and trying /embed/ or /embedvideo/ will load a bunch of things but then fail to actually load the video: http://i.imgur.com/V2smkiG.png